# Multi-threading a procedural algorithm

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I was working on [Project Euler #22](http://projecteuler.net/problem=22), and got my solution in about 9.6ms. Here's what I have:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSUInteger valueOfName(NSString *name) {
    NSUInteger sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [name length]; i++) {
        unichar character = [name characterAtIndex:i];
        sum += (character - 64);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CFAbsoluteTime currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        NSMutableString *names = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile:[@"~/Documents/Developer/Project Euler/Problem22/names.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
        CFAbsoluteTime diskIOTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        [names replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [names length])];
        NSArray *namesArray = [names componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        namesArray = [namesArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
        // Marker 1
            int totalScore = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < [namesArray count]; i++) {
            NSString *name = namesArray[i];
            NSUInteger sum = valueOfName(name);
            NSUInteger position = i + 1;
            totalScore += (sum * position);
        }
        // Marker 2
        CFAbsoluteTime endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        double timeDiff = (endTime - currentTime) * 1000;
        printf("Total score: %d\n", totalScore);
        printf("Disk IO Time: %fms\tTime: %fms\n", ((diskIOTime - currentTime) * 1000), timeDiff);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's a good time, but I started thinking about how I could make it faster by using multiple threads. With a quad-core CPU, theoretically I should be able to process a quarter of the names on separate threads and then get the total from there. Here's what I tried (replacing the code between the markers above):

```
__block int totalScore = 0;
        int quarterArray = [namesArray count] /4 ;
        typedef void(^WordScoreBlock)(void);
        WordScoreBlock block1 = ^{
            for (int i = 0; i < quarterArray; i++) {
                NSString *name = namesArray[i];
                NSUInteger sum = valueOfName(name);
                NSUInteger position = i + 1;
                totalScore += (sum * position);
            }
            printf("Total score block 1: %d\n", totalScore);
        };
        WordScoreBlock block2 = ^{
            for (int i = quarterArray; i < (quarterArray * 2); i++) {
                NSString *name = namesArray[i];
                NSUInteger sum = valueOfName(name);
                NSUInteger position = i + 1;
                totalScore += (sum * position);
            }
        };
        WordScoreBlock block3 = ^{
            for (int i = (quarterArray * 2); i < (quarterArray * 3); i++) {
                NSString *name = namesArray[i];
                NSUInteger sum = valueOfName(name);
                NSUInteger position = i + 1;
                totalScore += (sum * position);
            }
        };
        WordScoreBlock block4 = ^{
            for (int i = (quarterArray * 3); i < [namesArray count]; i++) {
                NSString *name = namesArray[i];
                NSUInteger sum = valueOfName(name);
                NSUInteger position = i + 1;
                totalScore += (sum * position);
            }
        };
        dispatch_queue_t processQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Euler22", NULL);
        dispatch_async(processQueue, block1);
        dispatch_async(processQueue, block2);
        dispatch_async(processQueue, block3);
        dispatch_async(processQueue, block4);
```

However, I'm getting a result of 0, but my times are about a millisecond quicker.

- Is this multi-threaded approach possible?
- If so, how would I implement it?

Comment: Do you wait on all blocks in the queue to finish before you print the result?

Comment: Errr…no…how would I do that (sorry, I'm just getting into GCD)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want loading the file as part of the timing?

Also, if you want to do them concurrently, you need to use a concurrent queue.  You are creating a serial queue, so all the blocks will execute one after the other.

```
// Create a concurrent queue
dispatch_queue_t processQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Euler22", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

Or, you can call *dispatch_get_global_queue*, and ask for a concurrent queue.

Now, when you add tasks, GCD will farm them out to available worker threads.

Now that the tasks are farmed out, you need to wait for them to complete.  This can be accomplished in several ways.  If you are using multiple queues, dispatch groups are probably the best approach.

With the same queue though, after all your *dispatch_sync*() calls, you can place a barrier block that will wait until all the previous blocks have completed, and then run...

```
dispatch_barrier_async(processQueue, ^{
    // We know that all previously enqueued blocks have finished, even if running
    // concurrently.  So, we can process the final results of those computations.
});
```

However, in this case, we are using one queue (though being concurrent, it will execute multiple tasks at the same time... though it pulls the off the queue in the order they were enqueued).

Probably the easiest thing is to use *dispatch_apply*, because it is designed for this exact purpose.  You call the same block multiple times, passing in an index.  The block gets the index, and you can use that to partition your data array.

**EDIT**

OK, an attempt at using apply on your specific problem (using your block code as example... I assume it does what you want).  Note, I just typed it in (no syntax highlighting here either), so you may need to play with it a bit to get it to compile... but it should give you the general idea).

```
// You need to separate both source and destination data.
size_t const numChunks = 4; // number of concurrent chunks to execute
__block int scores[numChunks];
size_t dataLen = [namesArray count];
size_t chunkSize = dataLen / numChunks; // amount of data to process in each chunk
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_apply(numChunks, queue, ^(size_t index) {
    // GCD will schedule these tasks concurrently as best as possible.
    // You know the current iteration index from the parameter.
    size_t beginIndex = index * chunkSize; // beginning of chunk
    size_t endIndex = beginIndex + chunkSize; // one past end of chunk
    if (endIndex > dataLen) endIndex = dataLen;
    int score = 0;
    for (size_t i = beginIndex; i < endIndex; ++i) {
        NSString *name = namesArray[i];
        NSUInteger sum = valueOfName(name);
        NSUInteger position = i + 1;
        score += (sum * position);
    }
    scores[index] = score;
});

// Since dispatch_apply waits for all bucks to complete, by the time you
// get here you know that all the blocks are done.  If your result is just
// a sum of all the individual answers, sum them up now.
int totalScore = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < numChunks; ++i) {
    totalScore += scores[i];
}
```

Hopefully, that makes sense.  Let me know if you get it working.

Now, if you ever get into a situation where you really need math performance, you should look into the Accelerate framework.  One word.  Awesome.

Comment: `dispatch_apply()` is a good idea, I did not think of that. In this "linear flow" type program one could also use the synchronous barrier with empty block to wait for the completion: `dispatch_barrier_sync(processQueue, ^{ })`.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, barrier sync would probably be a better choice here, since it's at the end of the program, and there's nothing else to do afterward.

Comment: How would you create that "barrier block that will wait until all the previous blocks have completed"? Also, could you provide example code for `dispatch_apply()`?

Comment: The example for using a barrier is already in the answer.  You use dispatch_barrier_async (or, if you want to block until it is all done, use dispatch_barrier_sync).  The code in that block will wait until all previous blocks on the queue have completed, then it will run.  I'll provide an edit for a simple example using dispatch_apply...

Comment: I hope that makes sense...  have edited it several times already for dumb stuff... there is probably more...

Answer (score 2):

First create a *concurrent* queue, so that your blocks execute in parallel:

```
dispatch_queue_t processQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Euler22", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

Then create a dispatch group, add all blocks to that group, and wait for the group to finish:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_async(group, processQueue, block1);
dispatch_group_async(group, processQueue, block2);
dispatch_group_async(group, processQueue, block3);
dispatch_group_async(group, processQueue, block4);
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Finally: Adding to `totalScore` is not an atomic operation, therefore you will get wrong results when all threads execute parallel. You must either use an atomic increment operation, or let all threads compute their own score and add the values from all threads after they have finished.